# in yii2 : why my default language is en

Tags: yii, yii2

how to change default language from en to another language

```
$config = [
    'on beforeAction' => function ($event)
        {
        Yii::$app->language = 'fa';
        },
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'language' => '/fa',
    'components' => [
        'jdate' => [
            'class' => 'jDate\DateTime'
        ],
        'mycomponent' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\MyComponent',
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => '******',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'codemix\localeurls\UrlManager',
            // Disable index.php
            'languages' => ['fa', 'en'], // List all supported languages here
            'showScriptName' => true,
            // Disable r= routes
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => array(
//                '' => 'site/index/fa',
//                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
//                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                    [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    /*
      'urlManager' => [
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'rules' => [
      ],
      ],
     */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

this is my $config in web.php

i want set default to 'fa' in root site !
 my site automatic change lang to 'en' in first time in any browser!

i try to change lang with

```
'on beforeAction' => function ($event)
            {
            Yii::$app->language = 'fa';
            },
```

but that is dosent correct  work!

Answer (score 1):

Remove this ridiculous 'on beforeAction' thing and just set

```
'language' => 'fa', // NOT '/fa'!
```

Comment: Have you got `enableDefaultLanguageUrlCode` set to `true`? Have you configured everything according to https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls instructions?

Answer (score 0):

سلام
ویدئو های آقای صیف زاده رو مشاهده کردین؟
لینک زیر آموزش های ویدئویی ایشون هست . در شماره های 17 و 18 و 19 
این موضوع رو آموزش دادن.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4ZlNlar4Ij6XzJrbVZOejRCcGM